# React to changes in System.Reactive

Tags: vb.net, system.reactive

new to System.Reactive, but as I understand this whole thing, we can subscribe to any observable collection and if something happens there, i get notified.

But as I am searching for a framework that helps me scheduling tasks, it would be huge to just have an observable collection that is already filled up with data, filter them by time and make them raise the onnext event as soon as some criteria is matched.

Lets say we have the class

```
Public Class Appointment
    Property Notification As DateTime
End Class
```

and then we have a `List<IObservable>` and we subscribe to it, and then we specify something like a `where` but not when something new is added, but when something matches. In this case, the current datetime `Now()` and any appointment

```
src.WhenWhere(x => x.Notification < Now())
```

Or should this be done with a custom observable?

Comment: This is tagged as VBA ... is that right?  Not that it matters, really.

Comment: Do you mean `List<Appointment>` and not `List<IObservable<T>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this ... note that you would have to put some flag on the appointment to say that the notification was sent and add it to the where clause, otherwise, once the appointment time is < DateTime.Now, it will keep sending the result over and over again.

```
void Main() {
    var appointments = new List<Appointment> { 
       new Appointment { Id = 1, Notification = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(4000) },
       new Appointment { Id = 2, Notification = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(7000) }
    };

    var q = from t in Observable.Generate(DateTime.Now, _ => true, _ => _, _ => DateTime.Now, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        from a in appointments
        where a.Notification < t
        select new { a.Id, a.Notification };

q.Dump();
```

}

```
public class Appointment {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Notification { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: hm, maybe this is the solution that does what I want and is also the coding style of rx. I mark it as the prefered answer. But still, right now, I think it would maybe be more beatiful to make a custom Observable. Thanks for your answer

Comment: It is very rare that a custom observable is the correct answer. I would actually argue that it is a bad practice to do so. Once you understand Rx better you will see that composition of the operators can cater for almost all scenarios. www.IntroToRx.com